# How to split the results of formulas in one cell over multiple columns in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Below is actually everything that is needed to answer this question.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula instead:

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FILTER(A2:A4&","&SUM(1,3),C2:C4=TRUE),","))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)
- [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: You are my hero..

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
=FILTER({A2:A4,SUM(1,3)*ROW(A2:A4)^0},C2:C4=TRUE)
```

**EXPLANATION:**

FILTER can take an array as its first argument. The tricky part is that every element of that array must have the same dimensions. While A2:A4 is a 3x1 range, SUM(1,3) is a 1x1 range. But this can be solved by multiplying SUM(1,3) by a sort of placeholder 3x1 array: ROW(A2:A4)^0. Since every element in A2:A4 has a row number, and any number to the zero power (^0) is 1, this just signals Google Sheets to give you SUM(1,3) "multiplied by 1 for three rows. And that makes the two elements of that curly-bracket array match up with everything else.

Comment: Really cool to see. How do you know all this? Could you recommend a course?

Comment: `ROW(A2:A4)^0` Why can't I just fill in 1? This is hard to understand.

Comment: Again, every part of an array must have the same dimensions. So you can't multiply a range of values by a single number, like A2:A4 x 1, because A2:A4 is three rows by one column, while 1 is just 1 row by 1 column. You need a way to apply the x1 to every element of A2:A4 (like A2:A4 x {1;1;1}. I could have used something else, like IF(LEN(A2:A4), SUM(1,3),"") or IF(ROW(A2:A4), SUM(1,3),""). You just have to have some way of applying SUM(1,3) to every part of A2:A4 so they take up the same number of rows and columns.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I'm gonna take another good look at it. I want to understand.

Comment: I get it now.. . This is so nice to know.